# SMS static broadcastReceiver called twice Android Kitkat

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat

I am implementing sms receive functionality in Android kitkat 4.4+. I am able to set my application as default successfully but when an sms is received broadcast receiver is called twice. I am unable to find the cause of this problem.

here is how I have declared my Broadcast reciever in manifest

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.package.SmsRecieverKitkat"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter  >
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: in this cases you will usually be asked to post logCat :)

Comment: Where is broadreceiver class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when an sms is recieved broadcast reciever is called twice

That is because you are asking for both `SMS_RECEIVED` and `SMS_DELIVER` broadcasts. If you only want one of those, only listen for that one.